# Update an EditText of an Intent from a variable of an object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-edittext

I will try to be brief and precise:

I have a user object that contains a chat, and this is updated every time I receive a message:

```
public class Usuarios implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1113799434508676095L;

private int id;
private String nombre;
private String ip;
private boolean isSInicial;

//HERE WILL GO THE VARIABLE THAT STORMS THE CHAT, BUT I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO IMPLEMENT IT

public Usuarios(int id, String nombre, String ip, boolean isSInicial){
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.isSInicial = isSInicial;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}

public boolean isSInicial() {
    return isSInicial;
}

public void setSInicial(boolean SInicial) {
    isSInicial = SInicial;
}}
```

I have an activity, that by clicking on a list, loads a new activity for the specific user:

```
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Usuarios e = (Usuarios) listview.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            Intent visorDetalles = new Intent(view.getContext(),Chat.class);

            if(Contactos.listaDeContactos.indexOf(e) >= 0) {
                visorDetalles.putExtra("indice", Contactos.listaDeContactos.indexOf(e));
                startActivity(visorDetalles);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(contexto,"Usuario fuera de linea",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
```

I need the EditText that contains the Intent to be updated automatically every time I click on a user of a ListView.

**I do not know what kind of variable I should use in the user object and how to implement it.**

Comment: "The EditText that contains the intent" .. What are you trying to say here ? Do you pretend starting a new activity or updating the current one ? I'm not catching your specifications

Comment: When I start the activity, by clicking on a ListView, this activity has an attached .xml that has an EditText, I want it to be updated based on the variable that each user contains, that is, the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Usuarios class add the variable:

```
public ArrayList<String> currentChat;
```

Instead of passing the index, pass the Object himself maybe.

```
if(Contactos.listaDeContactos.indexOf(e) >= 0) {
  visorDetalles.putExtra("usuario",e);
  startActivity(visorDetalles);
}
else{
  Toast.makeText(contexto,"Usuario fuera de linea",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

And in your onCreate Chat Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Usuario usuario = (Usuario) intent.getSerializableExtra("usuario");
        EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText1));

        String allChat;

        for(String chatLine : usuario.currentChat) {
            allChat += chatLine + '\n';
        }

        myEditText.setText(allChat);
```

Did I got your problem right ?

Comment: The problem with that solution is that I can only store one line of text. If for example they send 2 lines of text to that user, they would be losing one.
That's why I can not think of how to do it.
It would be like a constant update what should be done

Comment: @ManuuCarp That doesn't seem right. A String can hold multiple lines of text you just have to store it correctly. For instance you can separate each line with a '/n' . Anyway, you can also use a `ArrayList<String>` aswell.

Comment: Sorry, what kind of possibilities does that Intent variable give me that you declared inside the OnCreate?

Comment: @ManuuCarp You' re using `ArrayList<String>` right ?

Comment: @ManuuCarp I probably guessed the problem you were having. Check out my updated question, specifically in line `Usuario usuario = (Usuario) intent.getSerializableExtra("usuario");`

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!, I use a Handler on the for cycle, to update the chat if a new message come in.